# queries in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

in the above query it is giving error i want to fetch top record and store in some string variable of columns of query like string s=zipcd.zipcode

```
var zipcd = (from u in db.ZipCodes1
                                         where u.CityName == temparray[0].Trim() && u.StateAbbr == temparray[1].Trim() && u.CityType == "D"
                                         select new Viewsearch
                                         {
                                             Zipcode = u.ZIPCode,
                                             CityName = u.CityName,
                                             stateabbr = u.StateAbbr

                                         }).First();
                            Viewsearch vs = (Viewsearch)zipcd;
                            string description = (new ObservableCollection<Viewsearch>(zipcd))[0].Zipcode.ToString();


                        locationarray = vs.Zipcode + " " + vs.CityName + ", " + vs.stateabbr;
```

Comment: Could you please add the error message/stack trace you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var city = temparray[0].Trim();
var stat = temparray[1].Trim();
var zipcd = db.ZipCodes1
  .Where(u => u.CityName == city && u.StateAbbr == stat && u.CityType == "D")
  .Select(new Viewsearch { Zipcode = u.ZIPCode, u.CityName, stateabbr = u.StateAbbr })
  .First();
locationarray = zipcd.Zipcode + " " + zipcd.CityName + ", " + zipcd.stateabbr;
```

This should work.

Comment: var zipcd = (from u in db.ZipCodes1
                                                 where u.CityName == temparray[0] && u.StateAbbr == temparray[1] && u.CityType == "D"
                                                 select new Viewsearch
                                                 {
                                                     Zipcode = u.ZIPCode


                                                 }).Distinct();
                                    Viewsearch vs = (Viewsearch)zipcd;

Comment: i have tried this code and it is giving error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[ITClassifieds.Models.Viewsearch]' to type 'ITClassifieds.Models.Viewsearch'.

Comment: Why do u have to cast!!!, since you querying the first item by using .First() then zipcd type should be Viewsearch so u don't have to cast it. Would u please write the full error message

Comment: because i have to check if query contains result then store the column value in zipcode variable and if it doesnot contains store the blank value in the same variable

Comment: if you are using .First() and the sequence has no element it will though exception; otherwise you have a variable of type Viewseach and not a collection.

Comment: @Pallavi If it is possible that no elements can be returned, FirstOrDefault() may be more suitable. It will return null for zipcd, in that case.